# myproblem in uploading in php

Tags: php, upload

i have this page for upload:

```
<?php
require ('incs/db.php');
require_once ('incs/funcs.php');
?>

<?php


 if (array_key_exists('upload', $_POST)) {
         $directory = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
           $uploadHandler = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $directory . 'images/';
      //  $uploadHandler = "echtitipi".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. '/images/';
                 $max_file_size = 30000;
         define('UPLOAD_DIR', $uploadHandler);
         $ext= end(explode(".",  $_FILES['image']['name']));
         $name = rand(1111111,9999999).'.'.$ext;   
                 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadHandler. $name))
         {
             $upload = true;
             $title = $_POST ['title'];
             $sql = "INSERT INTO photo (id, keyword, photoName)
             VALUES ('','$title','$name')
             ";
            $result = mysql_query ( $sql, $con );
         }
         else
         {
             $upload = false;
             $msg = 'Cant Upload!';
         }
    }
?>
<?php

include ('incs/header.php');
?>
<?php

 getUrlQuery();

?>
<script language="javascript">
<!--

 function pick(symbol, path) {
  if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed)
    window.opener.document.form.img.value = symbol;
 window.opener.document.form.imgbox.src = path;
  window.close();
}

// -->
</script>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadImage" id="uploadImage">
            <p>
                <label for="image">
                    Tanım:
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
                <label for="image">
                    Upload image:
                </label>
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload" />
            </p>
        </form>
 <?php 
     if($upload == true)
     {
         echo "<a hrf(because spam!)=\"javascript:pick('$name','images/$name')\"><im(g) src=\"images/$name\" border=\"0\" alt=\"use\"></a>";
     }
 ?> 

    <?php
include ('incs/footer.php');
?>
```

`

this upload image to curretnt root's images folder. My current folder is admin:

root/admin/images

root/images

when i use

```
$uploadHandler = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. '/images/';
```

script doesnot work.

```
<?php
if($upload == true)
{
echo "<a hrf=\"javascriptick('$name','{$uploadHandler}$name')\"><im(g) src=\"{$uploadHandler}$name\" border=\"0\" alt=\"use\"></a>";
}
?>
```

the image couldnot add to editor. I guess There is a problem with javascript.
what is wrong in script

Comment: please put more effort into formatting, read the markdown help!

Comment: echtiti = http!!! because i cant send a link!
Its very very comic but can you tell me please that what can I write for http?

Comment: `echtitipi`? `hrf`? `im(g)`? There are so many strange things in your code that I'm beginning to think somebody slipped something into my coffee.

Comment: I think you you actually have a question regarding the JavaScript function `javascriptick`, but you haven't shown the code.

Comment: echo "<a href=\"javascript:pick('$name','{$uploadHandler}$name')\"><img src=\"{$uploadHandler}$name\" border=\"0\" alt=\"use\"></a>";

yes there is a problem with javascript. the code doesnot work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sorry for bad dictation because i cant write the right script because sending errors(link and images)

above code uploaded code to

```
/www/admin/images
```

and save information to database and add image to tinymce editor. But I want to upload code to:

```
www/images
```

when I use :

```
$uploadHandler = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/';
```

and

```
"<a href=\"javascript:pick('$name','images/$name')\"><img src=\"images/$name\" border=\"0\" alt=\"use\"></a>"
```

the image couldnot add to editor. This is my problem.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about an editor. Are you using some sort of WYSIWYG interface?

Comment: in popup upload.php window, after uploadin appearing image below the form. when clicking this image drops in WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a hrf=\"javascriptick('$name','{$uploadHandler}$name')\"><im(g) src=\"{$uploadHandler}$name\" border=\"0\" alt=\"use\"></a>";
```

change into

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript('$name','{$uploadHandler}$name')\"><img src=\"{$uploadHandler}$name\" border=\"0\" alt=\"use\"></a>";
```

I guess this will help...

Comment: For some reason, the entire question feels like a (badly-done) transcript of someone dictating..